# Neat way to apply Newton's Method

Tags: recursion

What are **different** and **elegant** ways of applying Newtons method to $f(x)=x^3-x-1$?

Newton's Method is: $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

Being a beginner I can't really figure out how to create the right code for cases like this. I have looked at Nest[] and Module[] but couldn't really figure out the right way. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: A `While` loop is is an easy way, loops are generally discouraged in Mathematica, but this is a simple code.

Comment: Have you searched the sit for "Newton's method"  yet? There are numerous hits...

Answer (score 9):

This is just a starting point, which obviously needs some tests for convergence etc.

```
f[x_] = x^3 - x - 1
NestWhile[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 1, Abs[f[#]] > 10^-7 &]
```

Comment: `FixedPoint` can also be used in the same way. +1

Comment: @C.E. When using `MachinePrecision`, the round off error may cause the method to never fix.

Comment: `FixedPoint` with option `SameTest` would work.